# data analysis about data clustering by vector correlation distance

Tags: r, dataset, data-mining

I am working on data analysis.

Given a group of data vectors, each of them has the same dimension. Each element in a vector is a floating point number.

```
V1 [  ,   ,   , … ] 
V2[  ,   ,   , … ] 
...
Vn [  ,   ,   , … ]
```

Suppose that each vector has M numbers. M can be 10000.

n can be 200.

I need to find out how to partition the n vectors into sub-groups such that each vector in one subgroup can be represented by a basic vector in the subgroup.

For example,

W = union of V1, V2, V3 … Vn

Find subgroup i, j, … t :

```
Gi = [  V1, V6, V3, V5, … , Vx ]
Gj = [V22, V11, V56, V45, … , Vy]
…
Gt = [V78, V90, V9, V12, … , Vz]
```

Such that :

Union of Gi , Gj, … , Gt is equal to W and there is no overlap among  all Gi , Gj, … , Gt.

Also , each subgroup has a basic vector that has strong correlation with all other element vector in the subgroup. For example, in Gi, we may have vector Vx as the basic vector such that all other vectors have **strong (linear) correlation**  with Vx. **Here, we measure the linear correlation betwwen two vectors not two data points.**

Moreover, we need to minimize the number of the subgroups, here, it is  " t " . It means that given 200 vectors ( n = 200), we prefer a subgroup G1, G2, …, Gt, and t is minimized. For example, we prefer t = 5 over t = 6. if t is more than 10, it may not be useful.

My questions:
What kind of knowledge domain this problem belongs to ?

Is it a clustering analysis ? But, in cluster analysis, one data point is a number, but, here one data point  is a vector.

Are there some statistics models or algorithm can be used to do this kind of analysis ?  Are there some software tools or packages that solve this problem ?

If my questions are not a good fit for this forum, please tell me where I should post it.

R packages do the clustering for data points not for data vector by correlation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are describing is very close to [principal components analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

Comment: isnt correlation is always between vectors, also if the requirement is that each subgroup has a unique basis there should only be one solution right?  So no need to minimize this... and the domain for this problem is linear algebra, maybe try the mathematics forum if no bites here

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to use a distance metric based on correlation, so you could assign a "dissimilarity score" between pairs of points based on correlation; I'll use `1-cor(a, b)` to compute the dissimilarity between vectors `a` and `b`. You could of course change this to suit your needs.

Then you can use a standard clustering technique like hierarchical clustering to cluster your points and visualize the appropriate number of clusters via a dendrogram:

```
# Build synthetic dataset of noisy 4-D points around 3 means
set.seed(144)
X <- matrix(c(rep(1, 100), rep(5, 100), rep(9, 100),
              rep(9, 100), rep(5, 100), rep(1, 100),
              rep(5, 100), rep(4, 100), rep(7, 100),
              rep(1, 100), rep(2, 100), rep(3, 100)), ncol=4)
X <- apply(X, 2, function(x) x + rnorm(length(x), sd=.3))

# Build distance matrix using 1-cor(a, b) as distance, and then cluster
d <- as.dist(1-cor(t(X)), diag=T, upper=T)
clust <- hclust(d)
```

From `plot(clust)`, we can see that 3 clusters would be a good choice (which is unsurprising given how we built the dataset):

[image]

Comment: I need to measure the correlation of two vectors, not two daat points in vectors. "as.dist(1-cor(t(X)), diag=T, upper=T)" do the measure in this way ? Thanks !

Comment: This is computing the correlation between rows of `X`. To compute correlation between columns of `X`, you would just use `as.dist(1-cor(X), diag=T, upper=T)`.